# How to get the scrolled distance in pixels in a scrollable div

Tags: javascript

I am building a Angular 9 app.
In this app I got a scrollable div (overflow: auto).

I am looking for a way to check how many pixels the div has scrolled so I can use that distance to get an accurate distance for the scrollable element inside of it.

The code below only returns the distance from the side of the window but I need to add the pixels scrolled too to get accurate value.

```
ui.offset.left
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the scrollTop or scrollLeft attribut:

```
element.scrollTop // The distance of the scroll
```